# How to send json data through file in server from android?

Tags: android

I have this API which requires me to put two files one image and one JSON. I have the screenshot in postman. How do i integrate this in my app?

[image: in postman]

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Please deliver some images and improve your Text.

Comment: @kwoxer i have posted the screenshot of postman. i have no idea how to do this

Comment: @NatigBabayev the API requires two files one image and another json file. i know how to send image file but how can i send a json file?

Comment: First of all, to make network requests you need to use a library, retrofit is one of the most popular choices for json requests. After that just read the documentation on how to send files as parameters. https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @Daniel i know how to send a file in server but what i dont know is how to create a json file in android studio programatically so that i can store the required fields by the API. The API requires the follwing fields in the json file to get an ok response
{
 "totalPrice": 500,
 "userId": 13,
 "deliveryAddress": "Bhaktapur",
 "deliveryPhone": "123124",
 "drugQuantities": {
  "1" : 15,
  "3" : 15
 }
}

Comment: use gson for this, retrofit is using gson to generate json from a normal class.